# POEDIT - Continue with translations

Tags: translation

I'm translating my web from English. I already found some .po and .mo translations in my language, but translations are not completed, so some texts are still in English.

Thing is, that when I open already translated .po file, every message there is translated, but total count of messages is 160.
When I open original english .po file, there are more than 220 messages.

This probably means, that I need to add remaining 60 messages into my translated file, and translate it.

Can you please tell me how ?

I don't want to translate whole thing again, when I need just 60 messages

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit .po files in text editor. Structure is very simple (some header, do not touch it) and a number of translations like that:

```
#: 404.php:21
msgid "Sorry! Page Not Found !"
msgstr ""
```

You can ignore comments started with #.

msgid - string how it appears in php code

msgstr - translation (if empty, msgid string will be shown on site)

You can find and simply copy 60 sets of 3 strings each from English .po to your-language .po by text editor. Then open poeditor and tranlate new 60 strings, or even simply do this job in text editor. You will need poedit only to create a new .mo from your .po file.